# Connection Error: attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time.Below is the code and also find attached

Tags: python-3.x

WinError 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time. Below is the code and also find attached.

import re
import shelve
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from ftfy import fix_text
import mysql.connector
import socket
import json  # used to move data in complex forms such as lists and dictionaries
import random

try:
import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
import tkinter as tk

try:
import ttk

```
py3 = False
```

except ImportError:
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

```
py3 = True
```

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import Bank_App_updated_support
import os.path

def vp_start_gui():
'''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
global val, w, root
global my_shelve
global prog_location
prog_call = sys.argv[0]
prog_location = os.path.split(prog_call)[0]
root = tk.Tk()
top = Az_Bank(root)
Bank_App_updated_support.init(root, top)
root.mainloop()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was trying to run a python code and I was getting the WinError 10060 message.